# How can I write my own OrderedDict class in Python?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, dictionary, ordereddictionary

Basically I want to understand how this thing works under the hood. I tried to create a list of tuples [(), (), ...] and each tuple will have two values, qst wuld be the key and second would  be the value. but this is not a actual dictionary and also there is performance issue as well (I mean read/write/delete operations.

So How should I write a class `MyOrderedDict` which will (probably) be extending the default `dict` class.

any hint or resource would be appreciated.

PS: similar functional we have in Django. `SortedDict`

`from django.utils.datastructures import SortedDict`

are they both same or follow same approach in implementation?

```
Help on class SortedDict in module django.utils.datastructures:

class SortedDict(__builtin__.dict)
 |  A dictionary that keeps its keys in the order in which they're inserted.
 |  
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      SortedDict
 |      __builtin__.dict
 |      __builtin__.object
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
```

Comment: Look at [the source](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/collections.py).

Comment: Looking at the source is a good idea, but the link Peter gave is to a really old version of Python. The [new source is here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/collections/__init__.py#l71).  Note that Python 3.6 is going to have it implemented in C.

Comment: @CodyPiersall : I dont think SortedDict works the way you are saying. I've updated the question details, see the docstring of `SortedDict`

Comment: Oops! You're definitely right about that.  I was thinking of [sorteddict on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sorteddict).  I'ma delete my super wrong comment.

Comment: You can look at the shorter recipe at [ActiveState](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576693-ordered-dictionary-for-py24/)

Answer (score 2):

The class would manage a dictionary and a list. Behind the scenes, for every standard dict operation it will use both:

```
Dvalues = {"foo":"x","bar":"y","baz":"z"}
Lorder = ["bar","baz","foo"]
```

To get a value by key, as a standard dictionary:

```
return Dvalues[key]
```

To get a value by the order m it was entered:

```
return Dvalues[Lorder[m]]
```

Add key,value:

```
Dvalues[key] = value
Lorder.append(key)
```

etc.

Comment: This is what SortedDict does internally. The downside is that removing an entry will get slower as the number of entries grows (unless you always remove the oldest entry), because the list must be searched linearly. SortedDict is a misnomer for me because this implies that entries are iterated in sorting order. The OrderedDict avoids the performance degradation by using a doubly linked list from Python objects which wastes a lot of memory on the other side. Maybe that is the reason to reimplement it in C for CPython 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at the [source in Python 2](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v2.7.9/Lib/collections.py#l26). It seems that it is implemented in C for Python 3.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: Why should that be a comment?